# How to negotiate a switch from full-time permanent to contract work

Tags: work-environment, united-states, tech-industry, distractions, work-from-home

My company does not allow full-time, permanent employees to work from home. I want to work from home for the reason that my office environment is very loud and distracting. They have policies of keeping all the lights off, not allowing work from a meeting room or from the patio or other locations on the property, and in the main office area people are shouting at each other all day long. My boss has indicated openness to WFH for contractors. How do I bring up the conversation with my boss about going from full-time permanent to contract?

As a side note we sit idle most of the day and bosses know that. So it makes sense to pay me as a contractor on an hourly rate instead of paying me fixed salary even on weeks where there is only an hour or two of work. And it will free up time for me to work on my business. It's a win win.

Also I have demonstrated that I am more productive at home. A few weeks ago I became sick with a common cold. I was still feeling 90% ok, but my boss said I could WFH so I didn't infect my coworkers. I agreed and worked from home for Tuesday and Wednesday of that week then came back into the office on Thursday. My boss asked me how I was doing etc. then we discussed what I did the last two days, I said I had finished X, Y, and Z tasks and my boss was astounded that I did all of that in just 2 days. Then my boss admitted I was more productive at home than in the office. So there would be some justification to convince of WFH.

Comment: You already gave the main point: They will save a lot of money by paying you only for the work you do instead of for the time you sit around. Just make sure that they pay you properly, but that is most likely a different question/story.

Comment: "My company does not allow full-time, permanent employees to work from home"  Yet you were allowed to work from home for two days.  Obviously the company's stance in this matter is flexible.

Comment: @sf02 Only in extenuating circumstances. Communicable illness is considered enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best answer here is just to start the conversation with your boss. You've made some good points above about why you think it would be beneficial to WFH as well as suggesting that it would be a help to the company if your salary switched to hourly.

It may be that you don't need to become a contractor as such (this has it's downsides) but a renegotiation of you contract is something you could discuss. Get it all written up formally before you start the new routine.

If your boss isn't open to changing the contract, then brush up your CV and find a new job... or start out as a contractor! To truly become a contractor, I believe you'd need to leave the company anyway (most contacts have a non-compete).