# How do I approach a workplace about multiple open positions as a contractor?

Tags: interviewing, applications, contractors

**Summary:** I work as a contractor for company, but would like to move into full-time permanent position there. How can I leverage my status to get the desirable position? I have one interview already but think I didn't do good enough job.

---

I'm currently a contractor for a decently sized business (500+ employees), and have applied to join one team as a full time employee.  I'm not sure I did the best job on the interview, so I don't feel like I'm in the running for this position.  Also, I haven't heard back after my interview and I'm a little scared to ask.  However, another team has a couple of open positions that I may be interested in looking at to see if they more closely align with my existing skillset.  I'm thinking about approaching the other manager and asking for information on the positions, possibly to apply, but I don't want to burn any bridges with my current supervisor.  What would be a good way to get the information I need to make an informed decision on the other positions without upsetting the status quo?

Comment: who is your immediate superviser?

Comment: this Q seems to be an opposite of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/147025/how-to-negotiate-a-switch-from-full-time-permanent-to-contract-work

Comment: Would this mean you finished your existing contract early?

Comment: Still under contract, looking to transition to full time permanent.  immediate supervisor is the head of the development team and directly under the CTO.

Comment: Are you contracted directly to the company or do you work for a contracting company and they have placed you are the client company?  If it's the latter case, there is a good chance of a "non-poaching" clause in their agreement.

Comment: working for a contracting company, this situation is usually contract-to-hire

Comment: @Aneirin, I think you can apply for as many positions as you want at that company because they have not hired you or officially offered you any position yet. At least, that is what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you think there are open positions that more closely align with your existing skillset. If that's the case, then it could well be to your and the company's benefit for you to move.  Assuming a smooth transition can be arranged, and you're right, a move shouldn't burn any bridges with your current supervisor.